# Java error: cannot find symbol when compiling

Tags: java, compilation

```
/* =================================================
 * Name: Kaleb Prichard
 * ID #: 140289
 * Section: CS 202 - 1
 * Program: 4
 * ================================================= */

import java.util.Scanner;
        
public class fourthProgram
{
    // This is where the program begins execution
    public static void main(String[] args);
    {
        double mealCost, tax, mealCount, subtotal, total;
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("This program will display a receipt showing the subtotal, tax, and total cost of the purchase.");
        System.out.println("How much does a MEAL COST ?");
        mealCost = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("How many meals is the customer PURCHASING ?");
        mealCount = keyboard.nextDouble();
        
        subtotal = mealCost * mealCount;
        
        tax = 7.5 * subtotal;
        
        total = subtotal + tax;
        
        System.out.print(total%5.2);
        //TOTAL is in dollars
    }
}
```

Every time I attempt to compile this code I receive an error saying:

> fourthProgram.java:13: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
> public static void main(String[] args);

I am new to Java.

Comment: [There is no `nextdouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble())

Comment: The method is `nextDouble`

Comment: It's `nextDouble()`, not `nextdouble()`.

Comment: Also, remove the spurious semi-colon in  `public static void main(String[] args); { ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nextDouble()` method is case sensitive. Notice the capital `D`.